# Performance vs Costing impacts of EMR clusters — many small nodes, smaller number of large nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr

As the title, I'm confusing on the `Performance` vs `costing` impacts of EMR clusters for 2 cases:

1. Many small nodes
2. Smaller number of large nodes

For example with instance type M4. 
m4.large: 2 vCPU, 8GiB Mem, 450Mbps Bandwidth, $0.030 per Hour
m4.16xlarge: 64 vCPU, 256GiB Mem, 10,000Mbps Bandwidth, $0.270 per Hour

- Case 1: 32 m4.large instances => 3724.48$/month
- Case 2: 1 m4.16xlarge instances => 3219.34/month$

With monthly fee, not different too much but how about the performance, which is better and Why.
Thanks.

---Upated---- 
I read from some articles and they said the performance of case 2 is better than case 1. But in my thinking, case 1 should be better (more massive parallel processing effect). Are there any one can help me answer it?

Comment: Your specs for m4.16xlarge are incorrect along with pricing. When comparing use ECU for total processing power with vCPU for core count.

Comment: Add more information about your use case. Do you need lots of cores / processes or very fast CPUs. The two systems are fairly similar but there could be a big difference if your dataset could be spread across a large number of systems for parallel processing.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I update some infomation

Comment: By use case, I mean what are you trying to accomplish? Describe in detail the data and processes that you need. Facial recognition will benefit from a different processor setup than calculating prime numbers. One note: EMR is designed for distributed processing with lots of CPUs (systems) lots of independent storage, etc and not one big computer.